# How to add LDAP login using Spring boot 3.x.x + Vaadin 24?

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin, spring-3, spring-ldap

WebSecurityConfig for LDAP login. I have used Spring boot 3.x.x and vaadin 24. I want use vaadin not controller but how to replace. In vaadin clcik on button then login form open using LDAP. How to do that?

```
package com.example.ldap_demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
                .and()
                .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
    }

}
```

and controller here

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ldap")
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/security")
    public String index() {
        return "Welcome to the home page!";
    }

}
```

please replce controller to vaadin.

Comment: Really, 3.5? Why not use recent, supported, secure, ... versions that have a tutorial https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security ?

Comment: thanks cfrick.
yes, I have used https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security in my other application but in this application I want to use LDAP security as per client requirement.

Comment: Makes no sense. What the heck is "Spring 3.5.x" ?

Comment: Thanks @peterh. if have solution for spring 3 with ldap then please suggest.

Comment: @Maryam: Please edit the title. There is no such thing as "Spring 3.5.x". What is it you mean? I bet you mean you are using **Spring Boot 3.x** but that is just guessing on my part.

Comment: You've tagged the question as being related to **Spring Framework 3.x**. Nobody has used that for many years, I would say. You need to understand the difference in the version numbering between **Spring Boot** and **Spring Framework**. Two different things.